# Saving a notebook as PDF, preserving syntax highlighting

Tags: front-end, export, pdf-format, syntax-highlighting

Currently, one may save notebooks as PDFs from the menu by `Save As...` and then selecting PDF (on a Mac, I imagine it is similar on other OSs). However, the resulting PDF does not have preserve the syntax highlighting of the code, even though things like plots are coloured. Printing to a PDF has the same effect (again, all this on a Mac).

Is there some way to save a notebook to PDF format so that syntax highlighting is preserved?

Here's an example of what I mean:

PDF:

[image]

on-screen (mathematica notebook, screenshot):

[image]

I feel that I am missing something obvious, but what?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The default style sheets set `ShowSyntaxStyles -> False` for the `"Printout"` environment.

You could change the notebook to use a style sheet that doesn't set this.  Probably the easiest way is to copy the definition from Default.nb, and modify it:

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"],
 ShowSyntaxStyles->True]
```

Comment: Should Default.nb be directly edited?
I have two such files, in \Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets
and \Mathematica\8.0\Documentation\English\System\ReferencePages\Symbols
which one is it?
None has a Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], ShowSyntaxStyles->False] line...

Comment: This is not working for me.  I tried (1) to run the code in the notebook I wanted to preserve syntax highlighting.  (2) Go to Format->Edit Stylesheet..., and tried to run the code under the Default.nb (3) same as before but under Local definition of 'All'.  None of these attempts worked.  How do I make this work?

Comment: @QuantumDot did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I never got it to work.  But, I am still eager to get it to work.  I have v 9.0.1

Comment: @QuantumDot I suggest you post a new question, referencing this one, and describe exactly what you have tried and what the (lack of) result was, along with your system particulars.

Answer (score 39):

The better solution that I have found so far shown as below:

```
SetOptions[
  SelectedNotebook[], 
  PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", ShowSyntaxStyles -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Response to Algohi's comment:**

This solution could also capture the `errors style`

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot didn't post correctly.

Comment: couldn't figure out the first answer and didn't like the second answer, but this one worked perfectly! =)

Comment: This answer is good however, it does not capture the errors style.
Try run `Sin[x,y]` and print.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG that is not what I meant. You have to run `Sin[x,y]` until you get error message `TagSet::tagpos: "Tag x in Cos[x]^2 is too deep for an assigned rule to be found"` you will notice that the color of the message is not preserve. Only if you set the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` to `"Working"` then you can get the color of the message in the pdf.

Comment: How to use this method as a default across all notebooks? `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout",
  ShowSyntaxStyles -> True]` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 26):

This is because Mathematica exports to PDF in the `Printout` screen environment.  If you change this to the working environment, it'll keep the syntax highlighting, but will also make everything a bit bigger:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

You can also change this setting from the GUI using `Format -> Option Inspector...`

If you want the effect to last only until you close the Front End, use

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

References: [How to export graphics in “Working” style environment rather than “Printout”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093559/how-to-export-graphics-in-working-style-environment-rather-than-printout)

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Brett. Now, how do I decide which one to accept?

Comment: @Brett's answer addresses the syntax styling specifically. IMO switching to a working environment so as to capture (solely) syntax styling in printouts is a wrong approach because, as Szabolcs notes you get different font sizes -- plus many other artifacts such as background colouring (perhaps), visible cell brackets, and so on that do not normally appear in print. If the syntax styling is *all* he needs then the stylesheet modification is the best approach.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think Brett's answer is a bit more general (in that it may be used programmatically), even if yours is easier to use for the specific purpose I have in mind. But thanks to both (there is no way I could have worked this out myself!)

Comment: I got this working by setting the `PrintStyleEnvironment` to `"Working"` but now the fonts are far too large.  How do I make it smaller?

Comment: @QuantumDot,You can have a try(@Alexey Popkov's method):                                                 `Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],Magnification -> 0.8]`  Or `my answer`

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I got using V10.3:

[image]

As you can see, `V10.3` maintains all of the formatting when converting to pdf. I checked, just to make sure, and the `PrintingStyleEnvironment` is set to `"PrintOut"`.

Comment: How was this done?  I don't get the same result when using File > Save As > PDF.  It is still uncolored for me in 10.3.

Comment: If saving the notebook as a pdf is not working you can try another method. Select all cells you want to save. Then go to the file menu and choose Save Selected As. Then choose pdf as the output format.