# Need help translating Mathematica code to LaTeX

Tags: plotting, latex

So I got a gift for a friend based on *Mathematica* code.

```
Rose[x_, theta_] := 
  Module[
     {phi = (Pi/2)Exp[-theta/(8 Pi)], 
      X = 1 - (1/2)((5/4)(1 - Mod[3.6 theta, 2 Pi]/Pi)^2 - 1/4)^2}, 
    y = 1.95653 x^2(1.27689 x - 1)^2 Sin[phi]; 
    r = X(x Sin[phi] + y Cos[phi]); 
    {r Sin[theta], r Cos[theta], X (x Cos[phi] - y Sin[phi]), EdgeForm[]}];

ParametricPlot3D[Rose[x, theta], {x, 0, 1}, {theta, -2 Pi, 15 Pi},
  PlotPoints -> {25, 576}, 
  LightSources -> {{{0, 0, 1}, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, 
  Compiled -> False]
```

And I want to translate this code to LaTeX. I have never used *Mathematica* before, but I've managed to find a computer with *Mathematica*, and I've managed to use the "copy as LaTeX" option. I couldn't figure out how to use TeXform, unfortumately :/

ANYWHO, I've managed to get this in my attempt to translate Rose(x,theta):

$\text{Rose}(x,\theta):=\left[\begin{array}{c}\left\{
\phi =\frac{1}{2} \pi \exp \left(-\frac{\theta }{8 \pi}\right),
 X = 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{5}{4} \left(1-\frac{((3.6 \theta ) \bmod (2 \pi ))}{\pi
   }\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right\},\\
   y=1.95653 x^2 (1.27689 x-1)^2 \sin(\phi );\\
   r=X (x \sin (\phi )+y \cos (\phi ));\{r \sin (\theta ),r \cos (\theta
   ),X (x \cos (\phi )-y \sin (\phi ))\}
\end{array}\right]$

(note the copy to latex option wasn't super helpful in formatting)

This is the result of directly pasting the copy result and trying to clean up the function. I'm wondering if this cleanup is correct, and also...what exactly is going on in the function?

**What I think is going on:**

1) We use $\theta$ to calculate $\phi$ and big $X$

2) We then calculate $y$ using $\phi$ and little $x$

3) Then $r$ is calculated using big $X$, little $x$, $y$, and $\phi$

4) The euclidean coordinates of points on the graph are represented by: $\{r \sin(\theta ),r \cos(\theta),X (x \cos(\phi )-y \sin(\phi ))\}$ , and that depends on big $X$, little $x$, $y$, $\theta$, $\phi$, and $r$

Is this right? Am I missing something? Did I translate something wrong? What does mod mean? Is it modding $3.6\theta$ by $2\pi$?

Also, what does the plot mean? I'm guessing LightSources and RGBcolor refer to how the graph looks aesthetically. Does the second part of the code mean that x ranges from 0 to 1, and theta ranges from -2 Pi and 15 Pi? What does PlotPoints mean? The fineness of the plot/ number of points in each variable?

I need to verify this specific equation with human eyes that know how to read *Mathematica* code. :/

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of citation-- this is *Mathematica* code from Paul Nylander -- a formula for the "Nylander Rose" -- I had no part in making this code at all.

Comment: Are you trying to understand the *Mathematica* code by translating it to $\LaTeX$? That's not a good idea. You can't learn *Mathematica* that way. Have you looked at any tutorials for the language? Maybe I misunderstood and you simply want [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42793/245) But your subsequent questions appear to be completely unrelated to $\LaTeX$.

Comment: If you wanted to use [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html), you need to prevent the evaluation of `SetDelayed (:=)`. To do that, simply put [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) around the entire code then put `TeXForm` around it. However, I agree with @Jens that it is not a good idea to learn the Wolfram Language / _Mathematica_ through $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @Jens : I'm not trying to learn Mathematica at all! I just want to know what this specific equation means (and literally nothing else). I want to translate this code into something readable, so that I personally know what's going on, without spending hours parsing through mathematica tutorials. I mean, at this point, I don't even know how to do whatever the Mathematica equivalent of Hello World is.

Comment: _"I'm not trying to learn Mathematica at all!"_ and _"I mean, at this point, I don't even know how to do whatever the Mathematica equivalent of Hello World is."_ indicate to me that this might not be the right site for you then... this site is only for people who are trying to learn/use _Mathematica_ and know more than the hello world :) Perhaps, gift your friend a real rose? ;) (Here's an example output of the code http://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Bfe.png)

Comment: @ R. M. Well, I am trying to learn how to *read* this code, and wanted to seek the help of people who (hopefully) know what they're doing to verify my understanding was correct. I know it's not learning the entirety of Mathematica for practical use, but I felt it to be well within the realm of the purpose of this forum. Seeing as someone did answer in a way that I feel addressed my issue, I think my assessment was correct. Oh, and while real roses would be nice, I chose this *specifically* because the giftee is a mathematician and would probably enjoy this sort of thing :)

Comment: You probably should have mentioned that you got this from Paul Nylander.

Comment: Ahhh sorry about that. You're right. The post is updated :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not answer, but an extended comment that displays a graphic.

The code you post in your question does not work in any recent version of *Mathematica*. It is syntactically and semantically incorrect.

The following modified code does work. My question is: does it produce the plot you want to translate into LaTeX?

```
rose[x_, theta_] :=
  Module[
     {phi = (Pi/2) Exp[-theta/(8 Pi)],
      u = 1 - (1/2) ((5/4) (1 - Mod[3.6 theta, 2 Pi]/Pi)^2 - 1/4)^2,
      y, r},
   y = 1.95653 x^2 (1.27689 x - 1)^2 Sin[phi];
   r = u (x Sin[phi] + y Cos[phi]); 
   {r Sin[theta], r Cos[theta], u (x Cos[phi] - y Sin[phi])}]

ParametricPlot3D[rose[x, theta], {x, 0, 1}, {theta, -2 Pi, 15 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> {Glow[Red]},
  PlotTheme -> {"NoAxis", "ZMesh"},
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", GrayLevel[.4], {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}}},
  PlotPoints -> {25, 250}]
```

Note: this code was built using your textual description as a guide to modifying your code, so if it does what you expect, your understanding of the code is essentially correct.

[image: rose]

Comment: THIS IS EXACTLY THE THING I AM INTENDING TO TRANSLATE TO LaTeX THANK YOU!!!!! Thank you for verifying that my understanding was essentially correct :) Much appreciated

Comment: This'd look better with `Mesh -> False`. In any case, Nylander's code was intended for older versions, and indeed [it runs as it is on 5.2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eYBfX.png); it is nice that you've shown the necessary changes for it to run on the current version.

Comment: If there ever was a chance to use the new 12.3 functionality `MaterialShading` then this would be it!