# Background color of Code cell lost when convert a notebook file to pdf

Tags: notebooks, pdf-format

Well, I have a notebook with the built-in stylesheet Preprint, which I'd like to convert it to pdf. Everything works well except for the code cells(I use the shortcut key alt+8 to create cells of code style)  with gray background. the code cell in the notebook looks like this: 
[image]

But, after saving my entire notebook to pdf, the gray background lost! This is a screen-shot of the same code cell above from my pdf viewer.
[image]

So, is there anyway to make the "code cell" in the exported pdf looks exactly the same as it is in the notebook? I mean, It should have gray background. Or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: If I redo the steps you describe, I get in the pdf this gray background.
Perhaps this is a version problem. Which Mathematica version do you use? I tried it with 8.0.1.

Comment: Depending on your intent (syntax highlighting too?) this is either closely related or a duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/451/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have read this post before and the first anwser to it(as you mentioned in this question) do solve my problem,but the pdf rendered in "working environment" looks a bit strange (too big!),so I would like to look for a better solution.

Comment: @mm.Jang You can customize the appearance by using a private style sheet definition as Chris Degnen describes.  The "Printout" environment has a setting `Magnification->0.8` by default which makes things smaller.  For example, go to Format > Edit Stylesheet... then paste in `Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"], Magnification -> 0.8]` and try saving a PDF again (printing environment set to "Working").

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much!It works perfectly.

Comment: Simple as this
Just go to cell, then cell type, then click in code.
Done. It at least worked for me in my Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notebooks saved to PDF are rendered with the **Printing Environment** that is selected.  The Code style does not have a gray background in the "Printout" environment.  You can change the **Printing Environment** to "Working" in the menu:

- **File** > **Print Settings** > **Printing Environment**

---

Combining this method with Chris Degnen's you can further customize the output using private style sheets.  For example, to make objects print (export to PDF) at a smaller size, as they do by default in the "Printout" environment, you can:

1. Open **Format** > **Edit Stylesheet...**
2. Paste: `Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"], Magnification -> 0.8]`
3. Close the style sheet

Answer (score 3):

You should probably be able to get it working with this addition to your stylesheet:-

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"],
  ShowAutoStyles->True, ShowSyntaxStyles->True]
```

Ref: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/May/msg00323.html

(Stylesheet for coloured syntax code printing.)