# What´s the best way to COPY/PASTE Mathematica code into Word?

Tags: formatting, interoperability, copy-as

As you can see in the image the code, with a standard copy/paste you obtain squares instead of "Return=New Line".

[image]

What´s the best way to copy and paste *Mathematica* code into Word?

One choice is a special PASTE, that gives me the text without colors as you can see in

[image]

Another choice is special paste as JPG/PNG.

**Is possible to copy "AS TEXT" with the original colors and font?**

---

The most usefull and simple solution I found is the Shutao TANG reply at [Saving a notebook as PDF, preserving syntax highlighting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/451/saving-a-notebook-as-pdf-preserving-syntax-highlighting)

Thank you for all the replies.

Comment: save selection as png (never use jpg for text) in mathematica and import picture in word.

Comment: Related: "[How to make Mathematica graphs in Microsoft Word independent from Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38715/280)" Also potentially useful: "[Saving a notebook as PDF, preserving syntax highlighting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/451/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thank you. The reply of Shutao TANG in the second link is the most usefull and simple SOLUTION from my point of view.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136497/export-mathematica-code-to-word-preserving-all-formatting?noredirect=1#comment368478_136497

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code notebook go to menu Format, Edit StyleSheet

paste in the following

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"],
  ShowAutoStyles->True, ShowSyntaxStyles->True]
```

select 'with interpretation' (upon prompt).  Close the stylesheet.

In the code notebook paste and evaluate

```
Export["eg.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Copy the colour-formatted text from the PDF and paste into Word.

Comment: ok, I think you give the solution. One question "where I should select 'with interpretation'?". http://bit.ly/1RIKC7z

Comment: I'm not seeing that display. When I paste in the cell text Mathematica asks straightaway if I want the text interpreted.

Comment: If I do this and "copy with formatting" from acrobat pro to word there are still font issues.  "take snapshot" rasterizes it and preserves the fonts, but the quality is not as sharp as saving as raster from mathermatica. ("save as" from mathematica can only do a cell at a time though )

Comment: I can usually copy most of the output as text.