# How to copy Mathematica code into Microsoft Word?

Tags: front-end, formatting, interoperability

Is there a way to copy my mathematica code (with preserved formatting) as text into microsoft word? Below is part of my code.

```
chemicalpotential1[x_] = A1/2*(1 - Tanh[B1 (x - C1)])*Kb*T1;
chemicalpotential2[x_] = A2/2*(1 - Tanh[B2 (x - C2)])*Kb*T2;
chemicalpotential3[x_] = A3/2*(1 - Tanh[B3 (x - C3)])*Kb*T3;

diffintermediate1[x_] = a[x]*x^2*chemicalpotential1'[x];
diffintermediate2[x_] = b[x]*x^2*chemicalpotential2'[x];
diffintermediate3[x_] = (phi[x] - 1)*x^2*chemicalpotential3'[x];
```

Comment: Similar to [136497](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136497/export-mathematica-code-to-word-preserving-all-formatting) and perhaps many others.

Comment: As a side note, just to prevent side effects, use `:=` instead of `=` when you want to use inputs on the right-hand side.

Comment: @Syed From the accepted answer of [136497](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136497/export-mathematica-code-to-word-preserving-all-formatting), I couldn't find the option Copy as -> Metafile

Comment: Which version are you running. On 12.2.0 it is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikflF.png). It becomes available when you have selected the cells to be copied.

Comment: @Syed I am currently running on version 13.0. I only see "Bitmap" at the end of the drop down lists.

Comment: This, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102747/4999, almost works. I didn't like the font substitution, and it didn't respect newlines.

Comment: @Syed I am also unable to find the Copy As -> Metafile option, no matter how little or how much I select in my notebook. I am using version 12.3.1 on Win10-64.

Comment: Metafiles were deprecated in 12.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Mathematica code to Word, preserving all formatting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136497/export-mathematica-code-to-word-preserving-all-formatting)

Comment: @user64494 No for me, since the Copy As -> Metafile option is not available for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: I don't know a better solution. I don't use Word much. I noticed the spacing around special characters (=, *, etc.) is lost. I doubt there's any way to deal with that in Word, but that's because I don't know anything about Word, except that its spacing is pretty bad. I was able to install Source Code Pro, the code font, in Word.

Comment: Okay, I am able to select a rectangle of the PDF, copy it, and paste it as a PDF "picture" in Word. I cannot select or edit the text in the picture, but it's vector graphics and scales nicely. (I'm using Preview on a Mac. Don't know how to do it on Windows or Linux.)  I can also "Save Selection As..." within Mathematica to create a PDF that I can then insert in the Word file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use MathML format:

[image]

---

2. Newer version of Office 365 support direct $\LaTeX$ input as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/340650/type-math-formulas-in-microsoft-word-the-latex-way).