# Export notebook as PDF with all formats

Tags: export, notebooks

I would like to export my notebook to a PDF File. I was wondering if it is possible to keep the whole layout, like `In[1]:=` on the left side. The cell brackets on the right side, syntax highlighting etc. So the PDF should be pretty much like a screenshot.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried "Save As" with PDF format? Alternatively you can print into a PDF using a suitable driver.

Comment: I tried both, but in both cases it only prints the code, without the cells etc.

Comment: Try to check "Print cell bracket" under "File->Printing Settings->Printing Options". The printing preview then shows a fairly good replica of the notebook for me...

Comment: Thanks that worked! The only that is missing now is the syntax highlighting, however I think I can fix that. There is a related topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check the following option: File->Printing Settings->Printing Options -> Print cell brackets->True (also available in the Option Inspector under "PrintCellBrackets").

[image: Mathematica graphics][image: Mathematica graphics]

To keep syntax coloring etc., please have a look at: [Saving a notebook as PDF, preserving syntax highlighting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/451/131).

Comment: This command seems to work, to keep the styling: SetOptions[
  SelectedNotebook[], 
  PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", ShowSyntaxStyles -> True]

Comment: @Peanut this is from the linked Q&A, right? Your question, while not a direct duplicate, benefits from the same solution. We might also mark as duplicate, but I am not sure if there is any benefit in doing so...