# How do I print a notebook in color?

Tags: printing

How to print a notebook in color?

When I select File>Print from the menu the output is in black and white, except error messages and lines in plots. I need to print the actual color version of the notebook, the "Working" Environment version to help students.

Comment: I suspect this is related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/451/69), unless there are other colors that are visible on screen that aren't making it to paper.

Comment: Check `File>Printing Settings>Printing Environment>Working`.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are exactly the same as for the question linked by  [Brett Champion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69/brett-champion) in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253704/how-do-i-print-a-notebook-in-color#comment634009_253704):

- [Saving a notebook as PDF, preserving syntax highlighting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/451/280)

But since you are asking about *printing*, not about *saving as PDF*, this may be considered as a separate question.

> I need to print the actual color version of the notebook, the "Working" Environment version to help students.

The obvious solution is to select the `"Working"` Printing Environment for your Notebook by selecting the menu item `File ► Printing Settings ► Printing Environment ► Working` when your Notebook window is active. Or equivalently, you could evaluate in this Notebook:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], PrintingStyleEnvironment] = "Working";
```

However, you will notice that everything will become larger upon printing because the `"Working"` style environment uses a higher `Magnification` setting. To avoid this and just retain the syntax highlighting, you could use the [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58612/280) by [xyz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9627/xyz) instead:

```
SetOptions[
  SelectedNotebook[], 
  PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", ShowSyntaxStyles -> True]
```